# JSON parsing - getting stock qoute price

Tags: excel, vba

Hope someone could help me resolve error on the code. I'm trying to get a stock qoute using API. But I'm getting an error on this portion. i = Json(1)("amount"). Error is Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch Below is the full code.
Thanks in Advance

```vb
    Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    myrequest.Open "Get", "http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/" & symbol & ".json"
    myrequest.Send


      Dim Json As Object
      Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)

        i = Json(1)("amount")
        ws.Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 2)) = i

    n = n + 1

    ws.Columns("B").AutoFit
    MsgBox ("Data is downloaded.")

    ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

    Next x

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is i declared anywhere? (Dim i as?)

Comment: Hi @JeremyKahan. i is not declared anywhere. Can you pls. suggest what should be the code instead? Thank you.

Comment: So I might start with Dim i as Variant to see if the error went away and to interrogate its contents. But probably eventually Dim i as Double.

Comment: Or perhaps Dim i as Currency

Comment: I tried both Dim i as Variant and Dim i as Double above Dim Json As Object. It still give same error code. :(

Comment: and that works or still gives an error?

Comment: same with Dim i as Curreny, still the same error. :'(

Comment: why Json(1)("amount") and not Json("Amount")? If you pass a particular symbol, won't you get just one? Oh, I see, it is within price. Maybe first get Json("price") and then work with that? OR even Json("price")("amount"). Or do a MsgBox(Json("price")) and see what is there

Comment: i tried the Json ("amount") and Json ("price"), no error but it did not give the result - did not return the stock quote. The MsgBox (Json("price")), the msgbox was empty.
The Json ("price")("amount") did not work, same error.

Comment: this is the result of request url. The code should only get the "amount". Example here, it should be 1.25. {"stock":[{"name":"FRUITAS HLDG","price":{"currency":"PHP","amount":1.25},"percent_change":5.93,"volume":24833000,"symbol":"FRUIT"}],"as_of":"2019-12-26T14:16:00+08:00"}

Comment: then I think you might want to go to index 0 in the array, but I'm not sure because of vba likes 1-based. It seems like you might want to build up from Json("stock") to Json("stock")(0) or maybe Json("stock")(1) and then Json("stock")(0)("price") and then Json("stock")(0)("price")("amount")

Comment: I think it has something to do with the JsonConverter. Cause the above code has worked perfectly for https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/SYMBOL:PM.

Comment: JSON format for Bloomberg API is something like this. [{"id":"FRUIT:PM","dateTimeRanges":{},"price":[{"date":"2019-11-22","value":1.6800000000000002},{"date":"2019-11-29","value":1.71},{"date":"2019-12-06","value":1.43},{"date":"2019-12-13","value":1.15},{"date":"2019-12-20","value":1.07}],"timeZoneOffset":8,"nyTradeStartTime":"20:00:00.000","nyTradeEndTime":"02:30:00.000","priceMinDecimals":2,"lastUpdateDate":"2019-12-26","lastPrice":1.24}]

Comment: while for Phisix.com API the json format is something like this. {"stock":[{"name":"Banco de Oro","price":{"currency":"PHP","amount":158.00},"percent_change":0.38,"volume":2245820,"symbol":"BDO"}],"as_of":"2019-12-27T15:20:00+08:00"}

Comment: I think it has something to do with [ ] and { }.

Comment: @JeremyKahan. I already resolved the error. i = Json("stock")(1)("price")("amount")

Comment: glad to hear you figured it out.